# Why header and payload in the JWT token always starts with eyJ

Tags: jwt

I am using `JWT` token to authorize my APIs, during implementation I found header and payload in token always start with `eyJ`. What does this indicate?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

JWTs consist of [base64url encoded JSON](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#3.0), and a JSON structure just starts with `{"...`, which becomes `ey...` when encoded with a base64 encoder.
The JWT header often (not always) starts with `{"alg":...`, which then becomes `eyJ...`

You can try on this [online encoder](https://www.base64encode.org/) and enter `{"alg"`  and click on encode. The result will be `eyJhbGciPSA=`

Comment: Awesome response!  And thank you.  For further clarification, entering {" is the 'ey'.
a letter will result in "eyJ" a number gives "eyl".

Comment: Nice, it explains it well

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the question, and answer above is a little too extensive/certain.

The best you can check for is (only) 'ey', as the first JSON member could be something else such as "typ" (rather than "alg"); I wouldn't recommend assuming the order of JSON members (even if they are supposed to follow a prescribed order - i.e. allowing for the possibility of real-world anomalies/a small amount of flex).

Also, as much as it is probably unlikely - as far as what is been produced by a particular implementation, there could be a (/some) whitespace following the opening (JSON object) brace character (and maybe even before it!) - I'm not sure if the standard/RFCs forbid this, but even if it's only a temporal instance of a bug (within the JWT generation process) this could in-theory occur; so you're better in only checking for 'ey' - as a quick smoke-test, before then proceeding on to a fuller/complete validation of the JWT.

(F.Y.I.  I believe it may have been Microsoft 'Identity Platform' whereby "typ" preceded "alg" - if memory serves me correctly (?), but I can't swear to it / as to where I've seen this being the case - at least at one point in time.)

Comment: whatever the first field is, it will *always* start with `{"` and then a letter.  the accepted answer is correct.

Comment: @ukrutt Partially - yes, but the answer also states "The JWT header starts with {"alg":...", which is not necessarily always the case - therefore is for some part misleading/that is the part that is potentially incorrect; ideally it should really be reworded (in case it causes confusion - when others' results don't fully match up / when their JWT instead starts with a property such as 'typ' instead of the "alg" property).