# Java io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException: Unable to read JSON value:

Tags: java, spring, jwt

I have following function written to parse claims:

```
  public Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
    return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(config.getJwtSecret()).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
}
```

And when I try to call the function with the following string:

```
yJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJicGF3YW4iLCJyb2xlIjpudWxsLCJlbmFibGUiOm51bGwsImV4cCI6MTUzNDgyMzUyNSwiaWF0IjoxNTM0Nzk0NzI1fQ.65PPknMebR53ykLm-EBIunjFJvlV-vL-pfTOtbBLtnQ
```

I get the following error:

```
io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException: Unable to read JSON value: Ș[Ȏ��̍M��
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.readValue(DefaultJwtParser.java:554) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:252) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:481) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:541) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at com.saralpasal.api.security.JWTUtil.getAllClaimsFromToken(JWTUtil.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
at com.saralpasal.api.security.JWTUtil.getUsernameFromToken(JWTUtil.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
at com.saralpasal.api.security.AuthenticationManager.getUserNameFromToken(AuthenticationManager.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
at com.saralpasal.api.security.AuthenticationManager.authenticate(AuthenticationManager.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
at com.saralpasal.api.security.SecurityContextRepository.load(SecurityContextRepository.java:34) [classes/:na]
at org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter.withSecurityContext(ReactorContextWebFilter.java:51) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter.lambda$filter$0(ReactorContextWebFilter.java:46) [spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscriberContext.subscribe(MonoSubscriberContext.java:40) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:115) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:115) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1083) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1083) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoBufferAllSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:117) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.fastPath(FluxIterable.java:334) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:199) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoBufferAllSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoCollectList.java:90) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:140) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList.subscribe(MonoCollectList.java:59) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.drain(FluxFilterWhen.java:287) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterWhen.java:131) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:244) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:202) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterWhen.java:190) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:140) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen.subscribe(FluxFilterWhen.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekFuseable.subscribe(MonoPeekFuseable.java:70) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal.subscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.1.8.RELEASE.jar:3.1.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.applyHandler(ChannelOperations.java:380) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.8.RELEASE.jar:0.7.8.RELEASE]
at reactor.ipc.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onHandlerStart(HttpServerOperations.java:398) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.8.RELEASE.jar:0.7.8.RELEASE]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) ~[netty-common-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404) ~[netty-common-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]
at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:322) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.27.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:4.1.27.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884) ~[netty-common-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) ~[na:na]
```

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Ș': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (String)"Ș[Ȏ��̍M��"; line: 1, column: 2]

no matter what I try I could not find the cause of the error.
Anybody have experienced the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much

Comment: the token you show here misses an 'e' in the beginning. Should be 'eyJhbG...'. Is this just a mistake when you copied it here or is it already the problem? When I try to decode your malformed token on base64decode.org, I get `Ș[Ȏ̍M`, which looks similar to the gibberish shown in your error. 
[JWT always start with eyJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49517324/why-header-and-payload-in-the-jwt-token-always-starts-with-eyj/49519717#49519717)

Answer (score 3):

> io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException: JWT strings must contain exactly 2 period characters. Found: 'X'

This means the JWT token is not the valid token and it does not contains the separator deliminator `.` .
Please check the mechanism from where you are generating the token for JWT.

Answer (score 2):

The string you posted is not a valid JWT. More specific the header section, which is the section before the first `.`, is missing an `e` which causes the error while parsing.

With the `e` added your decoded token looks like this:

```
{
  "alg": "HS256"
}
{
  "sub": "bpawan",
  "role": null,
  "enable": null,
  "exp": 1534823525,
  "iat": 1534794725
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JWT token is missing an `e` from the begin. JWT always starts with `ey` so
insert an `e` and check again.

Answer (score -1):

[Bearer Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuCgc.jpg)
If you are write Bearer keyword in the bearer area in the postman get this error.

Answer (score -2):

You are getting this error because you are not adding proper Authorisation token in your header , Authorisation token have some patter so do not temper it and use Bearer before your token (Example "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJmb28iLCJleHAiOjE2MjIzNTY1MzQsImlhdCI6MTYyMjMyMDUzNH0.XOtVjuiEKDg6m367hUA1qc9owqzkCe2OmsBB4_mRFcU ").

And your Authorisation token always start with **ey**.

Thank you.