# How to check that a given value is a JWT in a private route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt

Currently I have the following React component for private routes

```
    import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
export default ({ component: Component, render: renderFn, authed, name, ...rest }) => {

  var decoded = [];
  decoded.permited = [];
  var accesstoken = Cookies.get('accesstoken');


    if((accesstoken)){
    var decoded  = jwtDecode(accesstoken)
    }

  return ( //Second case is for iframe based renders
    <Route {...rest} render={props => ((authed === true) && (decoded.permited.includes(name) === true)) ? renderFn(props) : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />} />
  );

}
```

It works fine, if theres no cookie with a token it redirects to the login. If there is it evaluates your permissions included in the token and based on that lets you enter a specific route or no.

The problem happens when I insert a cookie with a random value, for example "undefined" , or "thisisarandomstring". When i do that, the function

```
 if((accesstoken)){
var decoded  = jwtDecode(accesstoken)
}
```

Is always executed , and jwtDecode crashes, so the app crashes.

I need a way to check that the passed argument is an accesstoken before attempting its decode. Or something like that for it to not crash.

Ive tried stuff like this

```
    export default ({ component: Component, render: renderFn, authed, name, ...rest }) => {

  var decoded = [];
  decoded.permited = [];
  var accesstoken = Cookies.get('accesstoken');

  console.log("first value")
  console.log(accesstoken)

 if(accesstoken === "undefined"){
  console.log("value after equaled string")
   accesstoken = undefined
   console.log(accesstoken)
 }
    if((accesstoken)){
      console.log("value in the decode")
    var decoded  = jwtDecode(accesstoken)
    }

  return ( //Second case is for iframe based renders
    <Route {...rest} render={props => ((authed === true) && (decoded.permited.includes(name) === true)) ? renderFn(props) : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />} />
  );

}
```

Trying to force the value to a real undefined if the detcted string is undefined, but it will crash anyway, because for some reason it still enters in that decode if.

I did that equal check becuase my app sometimes sets a string with the value of "undefined" because of some uncontrolled error that I cant seem to find elsewhere, so I wanted to control it from within the private route.

But anyway, the ideal scenario would be to check if it has a jwt format or something like that before attempting to decode it.

Any idea of what could I do?

EDIT: More info

It really never goes past the jwtDecode() function, because it returns an error

> InvalidTokenError {message: "Invalid token specified: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"} message: "Invalid token specified: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"

So im not really sure how to handle that, because the app crashes right there without possibility to handle anything

Comment: use try catch block here...if token is undefined or not a valid JWT it will thrown an error, which you can handle it in catch block.

Comment: @hussain.codes that did the trick .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
export default ({ component: Component, render: renderFn, authed, name, ...rest }) => {

  var decoded = [];
  decoded.permited = [];
  var accesstoken = Cookies.get('accesstoken');

  if ((accesstoken)) {
    try {
      var decoded = jwtDecode(accesstoken)
    } catch (err) {
     Cookies.remove('accesstoken')
    }

  }

  return ( //Second case is for iframe based renders
    <Route {...rest} render={props => ((authed === true) && (decoded.permited.includes(name) === true)) ? renderFn(props) : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />} />
  );

}
```

Using a try catch block, in the catch I removed the cookie so it wouldnt crash the app, since apparently it was one of the reasons it was caused, since a cookie was left hanging there

Answer (score 1):

If you need to catch the wrong token before it is passed to `jwtDecode`, you can check the structure.
A JWT consists of 3 parts, separated by a `.`, and the first two parts are base64url encoded JSON objects and always start with `ey` ([due to the base64 encoded `{`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49517324/why-header-and-payload-in-the-jwt-token-always-starts-with-eyj)) 
So you can check if the token :

1. has 3 segments, separated by `.` i.e. ..
2. first two segments begin with `ey`
3. all 3 parts have only charactes in the base64url character set.

That should make pretty sure it's a JWT. It's of course no guarantee, when you test with "eyXXX.eyXXX.ABC" the check passes and decode still fails.

In easy cases, when the `jwtDecode` returns `null` for an invalid token (I use the package jsonswebtoken on node-js and it indeed returns just `null` in that case)
you can do a simple null check:

```
var decoded  = jwtDecode(accesstoken)
if (decoded == null)
{
  console.log("not a valid token")
  // your error handling
}
else
  // continue with decoded token
```

Comment: it returns an error in the console ```InvalidTokenError {message: "Invalid token specified: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"}
message: "Invalid token specified: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"``` . That means it will never reach any of those if or else, because it stops at the error. Im trying to create  some kind of promise to fix that, but havent had luck so far

Comment: Hey i finally solver it with a try catch block, in the catch I simply removed the cookie and now it redirects properly. But thanks for your help